# No Wi-Fi adapter found on a MacBook Air 6,2 running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom, macbook

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my MacBook Air 6,2 with an Intel® Core™ i5-4260U CPU and Intel HD Graphics 5000. However, I am unable to connect to Wi-Fi as my system does not detect any Wi-Fi adapter. I have tried several solutions from the forums, but none of them have worked so far.
This is what shows when I run `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2`:

[image: code screenshot]

I've already downloaded the proprietary drivers (Broadcom 802.11 from bcmwl-kernel-source)  and my kernel version is 6.5.7.
Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: "I've already downloaded the proprietary drivers (Broadcom 802.11 from bcmwl-kernel-source)" Did you install the driver? Can you tether your phone and: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: The 6.5.7 kernel should be removed after booting into a 6.2 or possibly a 5,15 kernel and then see if installing the Broadcom proprietary module works after reinstalling it

Comment: @Jeremy31 This was the problem, I'm new to linux so yesterday I had no idea about this and the way i fixed it was by just reinstalling Ubuntu with an USB stick, but yeah i'm sure this would've fixed it as well. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem fixed?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to askUbuntu so how do I mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: @samusx0 You can't. Comments are just suggestions or requests for clarification, and you should instead anwser your own question if a comment helped. But I see you reinstalled, so you can make an anwser that you fixed it by reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by reinstalling Ubuntu.